# HTML page that have jQuery editable not working well when loaded into php page using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

My html page that has jQuery editable just working fine when open it through chrome, but when I load it from another php page using ajax, it's not well functioning.

This is my `online_store.html` page that runs the jQuery editable page:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <title>Online Store</title>
 <link href="../fontawesome-free-5.0.13/web-fonts-with-css/css/fontawesome-all.css" rel="stylesheet">
 
 <script src="../js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <script src="../js/jquery.tabledit.js"></script>
   
   </head>

<body onload="viewdata()">
 
 <div class="container" style="margin-top: 35px">
 <h4>PRODUCT</h4>
  <table id="tabledit" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
   <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>NAME</th>
      <th>IMAGE</th>
      <th>PRRICE</th>
      <th>DISCOUNT</th> 
      
     </tr>
   </thead> 
   <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
 <center>
  
 
 <div class="container">
  <button  class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#adddata">ADD</button>
  <button  class="btn btn-primary" type="button"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#adddata">ADD</button>
  <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="adddata" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="adddatalabel">Insert New Product</h4>
      </div>
  <form>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="productname">Product name</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="productname" placeholder="Name">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <label for="productprice">Price</label>
       <input type="email" class="form-control" id="productprice" placeholder="Price">
       </div>
       
       <div class="form-group">
         <label for="productdiscount">Discount</label>
         <input type="email" class="form-control" id="productdiscount" placeholder="Discount">
       </div>
       
       <div class="form-group">
       <label for="exampleInputFile">Image FIle</label>
       <input type="file" id="imageproduct">
       <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
       </div>
       
       <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
      </label>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
     <button type="submit" onClick="insertData()" class="btn btn-primary">Insert</button>
      </div>
   </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
  </div>
 </center>
 

 <script>
 function viewdata()
  {
   $.ajax({
    url:'admin_onlinestore2.php?p=view',
    method: 'GET'
    
   }).done(function(data){
    $('tbody').html(data)
     tableData()
   })
  }
 
 function tableData()
  {
   $('#tabledit').Tabledit({
    url: 'admin_onlinestore2.php',
     eventType:'dbclick',
        eventType: 'dblclick',
        editButton: true,
     deleteButton: true,
   buttons: {
    edit: {
        class: 'btn btn-sm btn-default',
        html: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil">EDIT</span>',
        action: 'edit'
    },
    delete: {
        class: 'btn btn-sm btn-default',
        html: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">DELETE</span>',
        action: 'delete'
    },
    save: {
        class: 'btn btn-sm btn-success',
        html: 'Save'
    },
    restore: {
        class: 'btn btn-sm btn-warning',
        html: 'Restore',
        action: 'restore'
    },
    confirm: {
        class: 'btn btn-sm btn-danger',
        html: 'Confirm'
    }
}, 
    
    
    columns: {
     identifier: [0, 'id'],
     editable: [[1, 'name'],[2, 'image'], [3, 'price'], [4, 'discount']]
    },
    onSuccess: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  viewdata()
    },
    onFail: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('onFail(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)');
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    },
    onAjax: function(action, serialize) {
        console.log('onAjax(action, serialize)');
        console.log(action);
        console.log(serialize);
    }
    
    
});
  }
  function insertData(){
   var productname = $('#productname').val();
   var productprice = $('#productprice').val();
   var productdiscount = $('#productdiscount').val();
   var imageproduct = $('#imageproduct').val();
   $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"insertproduct.php?p=add",
    data:"productname="+productname+"&productprice="+productprice+"&productdiscount="+productdiscount+"&imageproduct="+imageproduct,
    success: function(msg){
     alert('Success insert data');
     clearForm(this.form);
    }
    
    
   })
   
  }

  
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is their php code online_store.php

```html
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'register');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo json_encode(array('mysqli' => 'Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error()));
  exit;
}


$page = isset($_GET['p'])? $_GET['p'] : '';
if($page =='view')
{
  $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_product ORDER BY id ASC");
 while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
  
  ?>
    <tr>
     <td><?php  echo $row['id'] ?></td>
     <td><?php  echo $row['name'] ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['image']?></td>
     
     <td><?php  echo $row['price'] ?></td>
     <td><?php  echo $row['discount'] ?></td>
    </tr>    


  <?php 
 }
}
else {


header('Content-Type: application/json');

$input = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);



if ($input['action'] == 'edit')
{
 
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE tbl_product SET 
 name='" . $input['name'] . "', 
 image='" . $input['image'] . "', 
 price='" . $input['price'] . "',
 discount='" . $input['discount'] . "' 
 WHERE id='" . $input['id'] . "'");
} 
 else if ($input['action'] == 'delete') 
 {
    $mysqli->query("DELETE from tbl_product WHERE id='" . $input['id'] . "'");
} 

mysqli_close($mysqli);

echo json_encode($input);
}

?>
```

This is my main.php page that load the online_store.html into div using ajax

```html
<?php 
  
  include("authadmin.php"); 
  
  ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Admin Page</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/adminstyle.css">
 <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="../fontawesome-free-5.0.13/web-fonts-with-css/css/fontawesome-all.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="../js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <script src="../js/jquery.tabledit.js"></script>
      
 <script type="text/javascript">
 
 function onlinestore()
  {
   
   alert("test");
   $.post('admin_onlinestore.html',
 function(output)
 {
  $('#main_ajax_page').html(output).show();
 
 });
  return false;
 }



 </script>

</head>

<body>

  <header role="banner">
  <h1>Admin Panel</h1>
  <ul class="utilities">
   <li> <p>Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></p></li> 
    <li class="users"><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
    <li class="logout warn"><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a></li>
  
  </ul>
</header>

<nav role='navigation'>
  <ul class="main">
    <li class="dashboard"><a href="#"  onclick="onlinestore();" >Online Store</a></li>   
    <li class="edit"><a href="#" id="myLink" >Proofreader Services</a></li>   
    <li class="write"><a href="#" onclick="adminforum();" >Forum</a></li>
    <li class="users"><a href="#" onClick="adminmanager();">Manage Users</a></li>
    <li class="edit"><a href="#" onClick="salesrecord();">Sales Record</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<main role="main" id="main_ajax_page1">

  
  <section class="panel important">
 
      <div class="twothirds" id="main_ajax_page">
  

      </div>
    </form>
  </section>

</main>
  
  

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you view the page in Chrome, the Chrome is executing all the javascript appended to it, thus rendering the page with additional elements.
When you retrieve the page through php (ajax), then all you get is raw html that hasn't been altered by javascript.

I know of no posibility to apply javascript rendering in php though.

**Edit:**

There might be a way: https://sebastiandedeyne.com/server-side-rendering-javascript-from-php